# Extracting from string

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a quite complicated string that I need to extract from.

String - `!0A!0B!0C @0A@0B@0B`

I would like to read for each `!` and extract them as a set of 3 meaning `!0A` , `!0B` , `!0C` and then I'm planning to use select case to read them as each of them represent something (Will select case be good?)

And how do I extract them in 3s

Answer (score 3):

I would use regular expression. For example like this:

```
Dim str As String = "!0A!0B!0C"
    Dim ptr As String = "[!][A-Z0-9]{2}"

    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(str, ptr)

    For Each m In matches
        Console.WriteLine(m.ToString())
    Next
```

Sorry that the example is in VB but you get the idea from that.

Answer (score 1):

This method should do the trick. Send your string in, and a list of results will come out:

```
public List<string> StringParser( string s ){
  var list = new List<string>();
  for( int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++ ){
    if( s[i] == '!' ){
      list.Add(s.Substring(i,3));
      i+= 2;
    }
  }
  return list;
}
```

Note that this will fail if the string contains a ! without at least two other characters after it, so you should probably perform a test to verify this before actually running the substring command.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do that in many places in your code you can create a fancy extension method:

```
static class StringExtensions {
  public static IEnumerable<String> SplitInParts(this String s, Int32 partLength) {
    if (s == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
    if (partLength <= 0)
      throw new ArgumentException("Part length has to be positive.", "partLength");
    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += partLength)
      yield return s.Substring(i, Math.Min(partLength, s.Length - i));
  }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
var parts = "!0A!0B!0C @0A@0B@0B".SplitInParts(3);
```